# Middleman not rendering markdown and erb

Tags: ruby, markdown, partial, middleman

I'm working on a project using Middleman. In one of the pages (videos.html.markdown.erb), I'd like to add partials working with both markdown and Middleman helpers.

```
<h3><%= video.title %> : Récit de tournage</h3>
  <%= partial "partials/shootandlook1"  %>
</div>
```

It works fine except that Markdown is not converting into HTML... :-( 
I named my partial _shootandlook1.html.markdown.erb and my page videos.html.markdown.erb.
I really don't understand what I did wrong... Could someone please help me?
[The whole source code is here](https://github.com/celine-m-s/site-laurent/blob/master/source/videos.html.markdown.erb).
Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the excerpt shown above not part of the code shown in the link? If it's only 46 lines maybe it would be better to completly integrate it into your question and thereby avoiding the external link alltogether?

Comment: I'm so sorry about that Marcus, I forgot to push... [This is the right source code](https://github.com/celine-m-s/site-laurent/blob/master/source/videos.html.markdown.erb).
The page is quite long, that is why I didn't think it was good to paste everything. But I can do it if you think it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine if you name your page template file `videos.html.erb`, and name your content partial `_shootandlook1.md`.

The Markdown file will be processed first, then inserted into the ERB template appropriately.

I usually find that it's best to avoid having multiple template formats in one file, unless the format explicitly supports blocks ([like Haml](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter))

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathos, you really helped me :) It also turned out that I didn't activate markdown engine properly in my config.rb, so it couldn't work! Have a nice day!